# Regex to get Images from a Markdown Blurb where Image URI Contains a Closing Bracket

Tags: regex

I am trying to parse strings of markdown and capture the image urls.

For simple cases, this does it:

`!\[.*?\]\(.*?\)`

But of course it fails when you have an image url which contains 1 or more closing bracket in the filename e.g.

`![](http://www.example.com/image(9)Copy.jpg)`

How can I handle cases like these?

Comment: What tool are you using for the regex?

Comment: Match until you encounter a closing bracket and a space? How does markdown parse it?

Comment: I believe `!\[.*?\]\(.*\)` works. You want the regex to be greedier than it currently is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try making the closing right parenthesis greedy:

```
!\[.*?\]\((.*)\)\s
```

For the example URL

```
![](http://www.example.com/image(9)Copy.jpg) blah blah (yes)
```

this regex matched:

```
http://www.example.com/image(9)Copy.jpg
```

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/bU0wS6/2)

Comment: I don't even think you need it to be greedy, just not lazy.

Comment: Can't be greedy like that because it will go PAST the image markdown if the string has any other closing bracket later on e.g. `This is an image: ![](http://www.example.com/image(9)Copy.jpg) blah blah (yes).`

Comment: Won't that also match `[a](link).  Bla)`?

Comment: How about either greedy nor lazy? However, you can have it stop at whitespace `\s` to ignore that problem.

Comment: @robarwebservices If you can rely on a space after the closing parenthesis of the link, then my updated answer should work for you.

Comment: Yes, I think that will work in general. After reading the docs on markdown, technically for it to be valid markdown, the brackets in the filename should be escaped with a backslash (or html encoded)... so I will work that into the regex.